# Regex pattern match search over an un-ordered map in cpp

Tags: c++, regex, search, unordered-map

I have an unordered_map, its key and values are string type.

key is a regex.

Number of elements in the map is about 2,50,000.

I have to find the element whose key(regex) returns exactly one match against the string received in request.

When I iterate over the map by each element, in worst case it takes around to 10 seconds.

My sample code:

```
string string_to_match = "Find my Regex";
for (MyMap::const_iterator it = myMap.begin();
        it != myMap.end(); ++it) {
    //cout << it->first << "\n";
    if (regex_match( string_to_match ,
            regex(it->first,std::regex::ECMAScript | std::regex::icase))) {
        cout << ", " << it->second << "\n ";
        break;
    }
    ++it;
}
```

is there any way I could reduce the time taken...

Comment: If ordering doesn't matter you might want to try a `std::vector<std::pair<std::regex, std::string>>`.  You can get better cache performance out of it.

Comment: @NathanOliver What's that have to do with ordering?

Comment: Regular expressions are really their own little mini-language, and as such it will need to be compiled. This compilation of course takes a little time. You could save a lot of time by pre-compiling the regex instead of doing it in your loop.

Comment: @PasserBy One would use a `map` over an `unordered_map` if they need the data sorted.  Since the OP is using an `unordered_map` they don't seem to care about the order of the regexes and if that is the case using a `vector` will do the same thing but be more cache friendly.

Comment: If profiled, my money would be on the cost of `regex_match()` so I'm with @SomeProgrammerDude.  But yes, I would also go with `std::vector` unless the `unordered_map` is being accessed via, eg, `find()` for some other reason.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think I just misread your comment ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction of the `std::regex` object takes a lot of time because the regex input string is compiled during construction. So construct the `std::regex` objects in advance and keep them in your container of choice.

Calling `std::regex_match` on a precompiled `std::regex` object is very efficient.

Consider also passing the `std::regex::optimize` flag when constructing your `std::regex` object. This would mean even slower construction, but an even faster match performance.

Comment: Thank You..  Time taken by initialization process got increased by 300% , But the searching time is reduced to 20 % .

Comment: Is there any way I can do bidirectional searching

Comment: Can you explain your meaning?

Comment: My problem is, 
I have two Unordered maps, map1 an map2..
Map1 has a string in its value..
Map2 key is RegEX (compiled) and value is struct instance.

I have to loop over the Map2 to find the regex that matches the string in Map1.


Size of Map2 is fixed 2,45,000
Size of Map1 is depends on the user.. expecting 3000 unique in worst case..

Comment: You are giving me a description for half of yohr solution, but you do not explain the problem you are trying to solve.